# Specific UK country from Address

Tags: android, street-address

I'm developing an app which gets the users location and searches depending on which country they are.

My problem is that `Address.getCountryName()` returns the string "United Kingdom" when what I need is "Wales", "England" etc.

I have tried `Address.GetAdminArea()`but this always returns `Null`.

I tried looking through the returned address in debug mode, but cannot see what i need.

Any ideas?